# Query multiple taxonomy in Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, query

Currently I use:
`query_posts("post_type=listing");`

to pull all entries of my custom post type. 
But I have a taxonomy called status with the values of Available, Pending, Sold.

I only want to show Available and Pending on one page, and sold on another.

How do I go about this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the "tax_query" argument available since the latest wp release:

```
global $query_string;
$args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
         'taxonomy' => 'status'
        ,'terms'    => array( 'available', 'pending' ) // change to "sold" for 2nd query
        ,'field'    => 'slug'
    ),
);
$args['post_type'] = 'listing';
parse_str( $query_string, $args );

$avail_n_pend = query_posts( $args );

if ( $avail_n_pend->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $avail_n_pend->have_posts() ) : 
    $avail_n_pend->the_post();
    // show result
    the_title();
    endwhile; 
endif;

// use this for testing:
/*
echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']->tax_query); 
echo '</pre>';
*/

// rewind for second query
rewind_posts();

// second_query
$args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
         'taxonomy' => 'status'
        ,'terms'    => array( 'sold' )
        ,'field'    => 'slug'
    ),
);
parse_str( $query_string, $args );

$sold = query_posts( $args );

if ( $sold->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $sold->have_posts() ) : 
    $sold->the_post();
    // show result
    the_title();
    endwhile; 
endif;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error trying this: 

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':'` on the line of code that says:

`

if ( $avail_n_pend->have_posts() ) : $avail_n_pend->while ( have_posts() ) : $avail_n_pend->the_post();
`

Comment: See Update Then see which line it "really" is and fix it (use the edit button below the Answer)

Comment: sorry, I have tried every combination of code changes that I can think of but keep getting errors. That is why I didn't edit the answer. Still trying to learn how to do this properly.

Comment: n/p. I dropped it in the IDE and saw the failure. You can use it now. Btw: Download a copy of [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliossr2). This will help you a lot.