# How to pass URL parameters for advanced taxonomy queries with multiple terms for one custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, templates, advanced-taxonomy-queries

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16295/query-multiple-taxonomy-in-custom-post-type/16299#16299) provides the code for a query that returns an OR match on a taxonomy term:

```
global $query_string;
$args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
         'taxonomy' => 'status'
        ,'terms'    => array( 'available', 'pending' ) // change to "sold" for 2nd query
        ,'field'    => 'slug'
    ),
);
```

I'd like to have my taxonomy template retrieve the term values for the array ( ,'terms'    => array( 'available', 'pending' ) ) from the URL, the same as for the single term.

The point is to allow taxonomy terms to change over time, without having to hard-code page templates for particular combinations of interest, so that, if there's a better way, please suggest it.

Thanks to [this post](http://mondaybynoon.com/2011/05/20/revisiting-custom-post-types-taxonomies-permalinks-slugs/) I have permalinks mapping to template files as follows:

```
example.com/cptslugs                maps to my archive-cptname.php template. 
example.com/cptslug/cpt-post        maps to my single-cptname.php template. 
example.com/cptslugs/ctxslug/term   maps to my taxonomy-ctxname.php template.
```

I'd like to have something like:

example.com/cptslugs/ctxslug/term1/term2/

map to my taxonomy-ctxname.php template such that get_query_var( 'term' ) returns an array of terms (term1,term2) from the url.

but if I could get

example.com/cptslugs/ctxslug/?terms=term1,term2

to map to my taxonomy-ctxname.php template such that get_query_var( 'term' ) returns an array of terms (term1,term2) from the url, perhaps via a rewrite rule and a filter, that would be ok, too.

But either way, the idea is that the template file should work, whether it's passed one term or an array of terms.

**UPDATE**

Ok - [@scribu to the rescue!](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/comment-page-1/#comment-7134) -- maybe.  Kept searching, and this is what I found.  Thought I had it all figured, but I can't get it to work.

```
?tax1=term1,term2&tax2=term2+term3
```

maps to:

```
query_posts( array(
  'tax1' => 'term1,term2',
  'tax2' => 'term3+term4'
) );
```

which further maps to:

```
query_posts( array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'tax1',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array('term1', 'term2'),
      'operator' => 'OR'
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'tax2',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array('term3', 'term4'),
      'operator' => 'AND'
    ),
) );
```

example.com/?ctxname=term1,term2

renders the front page template.  **Revision: it renders taxonomy-ctxname.php when you spell ctxname correctly.  Imaging that!**

example.com/?cptslug/ctxslug=term1,term2

(taxonomy is registered with a slug of cptslug/ctxslug) also renders the front page template.

example.com/cptslug/?ctxslug=term1+term2

renders the archive-ctpname.php template.

How do I get a URL that renders the taxonomy-ctxname.php or the taxonomy.php template?

Then, once I get that down - suggestions for pretty urls are welcome but not absolutely necessary.

**UPDATE TWO**

```
example.com/?ctxname=term1,term2
```

and

```
example.com/ctpslugs/ctxslug/term1,term2/
```

Both render taxonomy-ctxname.php as desired.  See details in my answer, posted below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After adding

```
 print_r($wp_query);
```

to my template and examining the results, I have discovered URL formats that work.  I wrote, in my question, that the following format doesn't work -- in fact, it does - if you spell your custom taxonomy name correctly.

```
example.com/?ctxname=term1+term2
```

Pretty URLs with the '+' and ',' operators (indicating AND and OR respectively) are only recognized when **not** URL-encoded.

```
example.com/cptslugs/ctxslug/term1,term2/
```

produces the following WP_Tax_Query Object

```
[tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
      (
          [queries] => Array
              (
                  [0] => Array
                      (
                          [taxonomy] => announcements_cats
                          [terms] => Array
                              (
                                  [0] => term1
                                  [1] => term2
                              )

                          [include_children] => 1
                          [field] => slug
                          [operator] => IN
                      )

                  [1] => Array
                      (
                          [taxonomy] => category
                          [terms] => Array
                              (
                                  [0] => 1
                              )

                          [include_children] => 
                          [field] => term_id
                          [operator] => NOT IN
                      )

              )

          [relation] => AND
      )
```

While

```
example.com/cptslugs/ctxslug/term1+term2/
```

produces the following WP_Tax_Query Object

```
[tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
      (
          [queries] => Array
              (
                  [0] => Array
                      (
                          [taxonomy] => ctxname
                          [terms] => Array
                              (
                                  [0] => term1
                              )

                          [include_children] => 1
                          [field] => slug
                          [operator] => IN
                      )

                  [1] => Array
                      (
                          [taxonomy] => ctxname
                          [terms] => Array
                              (
                                  [0] => term2
                              )

                          [include_children] => 1
                          [field] => slug
                          [operator] => IN
                      )

                  [2] => Array
                      (
                          [taxonomy] => category
                          [terms] => Array
                              (
                                  [0] => 1
                              )

                          [include_children] => 
                          [field] => term_id
                          [operator] => NOT IN
                      )

              )

          [relation] => AND
      )
```

P.S.: According [to this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198606/can-i-use-commas-in-a-url/198850#198850) the '+' and the ',' are 'Reserved Characters' and can be used in the path, parameters and fragment of a URI, but may not appear in other parts of a URI.  I guess it's OK after all.  Just seems 'wrong' somehow, though.