# How do I query a taxonomy term range

Tags: taxonomy, multi-taxonomy-query

NOTE: The links will work If you copy & paste them. (I'm a newbie so I am not allowed to add to many links to the question)

I have a few taxonomies that I would like to query a range from, for example

- price
- age
- vintage

I found this question which helped me some

[How to pass URL parameters for advanced taxonomy queries with multiple terms for one custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/how-to-pass-url-parameters-for-advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-multiple-terms-for)

With the above examples I could query the age taxonomy as an example for the year of 10 and 20

- tax.jenswedin.com/age/10,20/
- tax.jenswedin.com/?age=10,20

This works ok.

But if I would like to do an query for an an range of ages, for example form 10-20 I would need to

- tax.jenswedin.com/age/10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20/

And if I would like to do a range between 10-100 you can imagine it will will not look that good.

So I tried to put the age terms in sub taxonomy terms so the structure would be like this

- 11-20

  - 11
  - 12
  - 13
  - 14
  - 15
  - 16
  - 17
  - 18
  - 19
- 21-30

  - ...
  - ...

By doing this I could now query like this

- tax.jenswedin.com/age/11-20/

And it would work, it would show all ages within 11-20

But this way is quite inflexible, I would need just range between 15-20 this wouldn't work.

What I would like to know if there is a way that the range is dynamic and more flexible. I know that @scribu had a plugin (which isn't supported longer) that had the had support for ranges with the min & max for custom fields. But I haven't seen anything like this for taxonomies.

- chwisgi.com/?age-min=20&age-max=30

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the query var and programatically expand the numbers between your minimum value and maximum value.

Assuming http://tax.jenswedin.com/age/10,20/ is rewritten to http://tax.jenswedin.com/?age=10,20, then (pseudo code)

```
$parts = explode(get_query_var('age'), ',');
$min_val = $parts[0]; // Should be 10 in this example
$max_val = $parts[1]; // Should be 20 in this example
$range = range($min_val, $max_val); // http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php
/* Blah blah blah lets jump to where you need to query the terms */
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'age',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $range
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This works well for things like numbers. But you could do a `foreach` loop over the $range array and make the values whatever you need them be.