# Displaying custom taxonomy menu in custom post type archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I have two post types "restaurant" & "pub", they both share same custom taxonomy "country". And I display each post type in archive page.

What I want to do is, when I visit "restaurant" archive page, there is the taxonomy "country" terms listed as the menu in that page. The terms has to be from the posts that created in "restaurant" post type, so when user click on the terms (let say "US"), it will display the posts from "restaurant" that in "US".

Here is the illustration:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Displaying two different menus base on the archive is no problem using `is_post_type_archive()`

What you are looking for is essentially the link to an term archive that only contains posts of a certain post type. Something like `/index.php?term=US&post_type=pub`. As far as I'm aware of WordPress doesn't offer this natively.

You will have to create your own page template and rewrite rules to make it display like `/restaurants/fr`.
I think this questions covers enough about that:
[How to pass URL parameters for advanced taxonomy queries with multiple terms for one custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/how-to-pass-url-parameters-for-advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-multiple-terms-for)

Comment: It works, but it shows these error: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$labels in /wp-includes/general-template.php on line 665 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-includes/general-template.php on line 665