# Formulate a url to show posts with both taxonomy terms

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms, pre-get-posts, multi-taxonomy-query

I would like to show an archive of posts that have two taxonomy terms in common. So for example, I'd like to show all posts that have *both* the terms "sauce" and "cheese" in the custom `food` taxonomy.

The trick is that I'd like to do this using the url. The closest I've come is with:

```
example.com?food[]=sauce&food[]=cheese
```

Upon inspecting the $query from the `pre_get_posts` filter, I can see that:

```
WP_Tax_Query::__set_state(array(
   'queries' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'taxonomy' => 'food',
      'terms' => 
      array (
        0 => 'sauce',
        1 => 'cheese',
      ),
      'field' => 'slug',
      'operator' => 'IN',
      'include_children' => true,
    ),
  ),
```

So then I change the `operator` to `AND` like so:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {

    $query->tax_query->queries[0]['operator'] = 'AND';

});
```

But my results are always including posts that have *at least* one term instead of posts that have *all* terms.

According to Query Monitor, the main query is as such (and you can see that it's looking for posts that have *either* of the two term IDs.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (6,9) )
```

So, how can I formulate a url to get only posts with *both* taxonomy-terms?

Comment: Tried https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/how-to-pass-url-parameters-for-advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-multiple-terms-for but it didn't work for me

Comment: How is your statement that modifies the logic to `AND` called?  Is it also called with `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: @jdm2112 Thanks for looking, I've updated the code, and yes, that is wrapped in the pre_get_posts action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I registered my taxonomy, I left out the argument for 'rewrite', which then defaulted to `true`. So by default, WordPress wanted to rewrite the url as `/food/whatever/`. The tricky thing was that it *did* accept the format `?food=whatever` , but wouldn't accept two different terms in that format when joined with a plus.

The solution was to specify the rewrite arg of `register_taxonomy()` like so:

```
register_taxonomy( 'food', 'post', [
   ...
   'rewrite' => [
      'slug' => 'filter',
      'with_front' => false,
   ],
   ...
]);
```

And then I can use `/food/sauce+cheese` like @jdm2112 and the docs specify.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can define the `AND` logical operator with the URL parameters, specifically adding the "+" between your terms like this:
`url?taxonomy=term1+term2`

This will ensure that only posts containing all terms listed are returned.

Example:
https://example.com/blog?food=sauce+cheese

```
[tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
        (
        [queries] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => food
                        [terms] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => sauce
                            )
                        [field] => slug
                        [operator] => IN
                        [include_children] => 1
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => food
                        [terms] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => cheese
                            )
                        [field] => slug
                        [operator] => IN
                        [include_children] => 1
                    )
            )
        [relation] => AND
```

Notice the relation is definitely AND between the terms.

In local testing, I can confirm the returned posts are only those that contain BOTH terms.

Comment: Ok, that _does_ work... but only when I have permalinks rewriting turned off. With  permalink writing on, `?food=sauce+cheese` is getting rewritten to `/food/sauce`. I also tried setting `rewrite=>false` in the register_taxonomy() call, but it still removed the second item and changed it to `?food=sauce`

Comment: Right. So you want to retain the query string parameters instead of having WP rewrite these taxonomy archive URLs? Not sure if there is a way to work that with the WP_Rewrite API or not. Essentially do not rewrite the URL if the request meets certain conditions?  If so, please add to your question above for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Actually, no I don't _actually_ care what the url looks like. In my comment, I only meant that when I join two terms with the plus sign (as you suggested), the second one gets stripped out. And that happens when pretty-permalinks are on (as they are on the vast majority of sites). It does _not_ happen with no pretty permalinks. I don't have any custom rewrite logic. When you tested, did you happen to do with raw query strings or pretty permalinks?

Comment: On my test site permalinks are on, using a custom structure "/blog/%postname%".  My testing uses the tax and terms as a query string and the URL is not rewritten -  http://example.local/blog?food=sauce+cheese